# How to create a Bootstrap accordion from a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, recursion, accordion

I have a nested dictionary like this one:

```
d = {1: {4: {6: {}, 7: {}, 8: {}}, 5: {}}, 2: {}, 3: {}}
```

Which can be visualized as:

```
1
    4
       6
       7
       8
    5
2
3
```

My goal is to create a bootstrap accordion like the one give by this link: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/QQOZRe?editors=1000

Here there is a screenshot:

[image]

In order to achieve my goal I figured that I could generate the  html code in a python script that can be rendered using flask. The code I came up with is this:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0, indent_before=0):
    html_code = ''
    for key, value in d.items():
            
        if indent > indent_before:
            html_code += """
            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="accordion-1-1">
            """
        elif indent == indent_before:
            html_code += """
            </div>
            """
        else:
            html_code += """
            </div>
            """*indent

        html_code +="""
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-{}">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-{}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{}">
                            {}
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
        """.format(key ,key, key, key, indent)
        #print('\t' * (indent) + str(key) + '({})({})\n'.format(indent,indent_before))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            html_code  += pretty(value, indent+1, indent) 
        else:
            print('\t' * (indent+1) + str(value))

    return html_code
        
msg = pretty(result)
print(msg)
```

Basically it is a recursive function that iterates through all the dictionary items. However this code has 3 measure errors which I don't know how to fix:

- The accordion references do not change every time a new layer is added
- A class="collapse" div is added before every item
- I cannot close the divs correctly as I lose track of how many items have been added up to each level.

The output that I get is the following:

```
<div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                            1
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="accordion-1-1">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-4">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-4">
                            4
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="accordion-1-1">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-6">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-6">
                            6
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="accordion-1-1">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-7">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-7" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-7">
                            7
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="accordion-1-1">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-8">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-8">
                            8
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="accordion-1-1">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-5">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-5">
                            5
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
                            2
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-3">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
                            3
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
```

Would you be able to propose a smart and elegant way to generate the accordion starting from the dictionary? You can modify the code as you want as long as I get the html code that I can then render. I also thought of using Jinja2 but I have no clue about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reach my result on my real problem. Here is the code:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0, indent_previous_layer=-1, counter=0):
    html_code = ''
    indent_privious_item = indent_previous_layer
    for key, value in d.items():             
            
        if indent > indent_privious_item and counter!=0:
            html_code += """
            <div id="collapse-{}" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{}" aria-labelledby="heading-{}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="accordion-{}">
            """.format(counter, indent-1, counter, indent)
        elif indent == indent_privious_item:
            html_code += """
            </div>
            """
            if indent==0:
                html_code += """
                <!--End of Card-->
                """
        elif indent < indent_privious_item:
            if indent==0:
                html_code += """
                                </div>
                """
                html_code += """
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                """*(indent_privious_item-indent)
                html_code += """
                <!--End of Card-->
                """
            else:
                html_code += """
                                </div>
                """
                html_code += """
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                """*(indent_privious_item-indent)

        html_code +="""
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading-{}">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-{}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-{}">
                 Depth Level {}
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>
            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                <!--h5 class="card-title"></h5-->
                <p class="card-text">{}</p>
                    <ul class="list-group">""".format(counter+1, counter+1, counter+1, indent, "Some text")

        html_code += """
                    </ul>
            </div>
    
            """

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            code, indent_privious_item, counter = pretty(value, indent+1, indent, counter+1)
            html_code += code
        else:
            print('\t' * (indent+1) + str(value))
        
    return html_code, indent_privious_item, counter
```

Note: the indentation may be off. Feel free to fix it